# Django 2 models 1 form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So, I'm still a total noob at Django and I was wondering how to do the following:

So lets say that I have something like the below code:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #Some fields
class UserProfileOther(models.Model):
    #Some other fields that I want in another table for organization
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile)
```

How do I now create a form that includes both of the above models?

Comment: In my experience, you would create a 3rd FormClass, form (not model!) and then use its _save_ to correctly write data back. It gives you much more flexibility over display of your forms.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have both models in the same form? Are you just trying to make a single HTML form (so the user only has to submit once)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two separate ModelForm classes. But in your view, you have to add a prefix to their instances.

```
def viewname(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = forms.YourForm(request.POST, prefix="form1")
        form2 = forms.YourOtherForm(request.POST, prefix="form2")
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            # process valid forms
    else:
        form1 = forms.YourForm(prefix="form1")
        form2 = forms.YourOtherForm(prefix="form2")

    ....
```

Using a prefix ensures that fields with similar names are not mixed up.

Comment: This way, if form1 is not valid it will not continue validating form2 and not show it's errors.

Comment: In that case you can do form1_valid=form1.is_valid() + form2_valid=form2.is_valid() and then if form1_valid and form2_valid: ...

Comment: Anyone know how to do this with class based views?

Comment: @umami, there are currently no class based generic views that are made for this scenario. But I've heard talk that it is going to arrive at some point. Until then, it's not really a hard problem solve by implementing your own post() etc.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem is what [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to create a form based on the first model, and then to create a form based on the second model that inherits the first form. Meaning:

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
       ...

class UserProfileOtherForm(UserProfileForm):
       ...

And pass the `UserProfileOtherForm` to form template. It worked for me. Not sure if there is a simpler approach.