# Django save data from individual form elements (text boxes)

Tags: python, html, django, post

I have a simple form where there is a username and a message. Upon clicking the submit button, I want the data for user and message to be stored separately into the database. However, I am unable to figure out where in my 'index.html' template should I include 'user' and 'message'. Now I am receiving an IntegrityError on m.save().

```
 "Exception Value: SimpleMessage_message.content may not be NULL"
```

Models

```
class User (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.name

class Message (models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.content
```

views.py

```
def index (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    u = User(name=request.POST.get('user'))
    m = Message(content=request.POST.get('text'), user = u)
        u.save()
        m.save()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {
                'user': u,
                'message': m,
                }, RequestContext(request))
    else:
        u = User()
        m = Message()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {
                'user': u,
                'message': m,
                }, RequestContext(request)
```

)

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="20" placeholder = "Username">
<br>
<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="35" name="text" maxlength="140" placeholder = "Message goes here"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: When you look at the generated HTML, do you see the CSRF token.

Comment: What would the CSRF token look like? I see the two text boxes for username and message, as well as the submit button.

Comment: It would be a tag like `<input type="hidden" value="123">`.

Comment: No, I do not see that

Comment: Did you not notice that the error message gives you *detailed* instructions on how to solve the problem?

Comment: The csrf_token portion wasn't the main part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive the error `CSRF token missing or incorrect.`, and you don't see the CSRF token in the HTML source, you should make sure that you are using a `RequestContext`:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

...

return render_to_response('index.html', {
            'user': u,
            'message': m,
            }, RequestContext(request))
```

This will make the `{% csrf_token %}` tag available to your template, and if it worked you should see `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="somevaluehere"/>` in the HTML source.

(From a first glance, it looks like the rest of your code should work as expected, creating both User and Message entries)

Comment: Now I am receiving an IntegrityError on m.save(). "Exception Value: SimpleMessage_message.content may not be NULL"

Comment: @user1530318 You should probably look at using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) instead of raw input HTML fields

Comment: I tried it with forms but for some reason I was unable to save my form data to the respective models...

Comment: Is it possible to relay the responses from the form back to the original User and Message models?

Comment: @user1530318 I can't really answer all this in comments; maybe ask a new question, or look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512972/django-2-models-1-form - that's the correct way of handling this situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520728/django-convert-current-model-raw-html-input-to-form-to-save-input-data