# Django convert current model/raw HTML input to Form to save input data

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a simple form where there is a username and a message. Upon clicking the submit button, I want the data for user and message to be stored separately into the database. I am currently receiving an IntegrityError on `m.save()`

```
 "Exception Value: SimpleMessage_message.content may not be NULL"
```

and was told to instead use forms to accomplish this. However, I am confused as to how to use a form to pass in form data to the individual User and Message Models so that the input data is saved in the database.

Models

```
class User (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.name

class Message (models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):              
        return self.content
```

views.py

```
def index (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u = User(name=request.POST.get('user'))
        u.save()
        m = Message(content=request.POST.get('text'), user = u)
        m.save()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {
                'user': u,
                'message': m,
                }, RequestContext(request))
    else:
        u = User()
        m = Message()
        return render_to_response('index.html', {
                'user': u,
                'message': m,
                }, RequestContext(request)
```

)

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="20" placeholder = "Username">
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="35" id="text" name="text" maxlength="140" placeholder = "Message goes here"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: also paste forms.py .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model so that `content` can be null:

```
class Message (models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
```

Or give a default value in the form:

```
m = Message(content=request.POST.get('text', ' '), user = u)
```