# CSRF verification failure for single form with two models

Tags: python, django, csrf

Working with Django, I have a model `Foo` with a foreign key to a model `Bar`. When I create a `Foo` object on my site, I want to be able to set attributes of the `Bar` object in the same form.

I'm able to set the view and template up to use these two models in the same form. However, when I go to submit the form, I get a 403 Forbidden error saying:

> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

I have a the `{% csrf_token %}` tag in my form, so I'm not sure how to fix this. Does anyone have any ideas?

In my views.py:

```
def foo_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fooForm = FooForm(request.POST, instance=Foo())
        barForm = BarForm(request.POST, instance=Bar())
        if fooForm.is_valid() and barForm.is_valid():
            foo = fooForm.save()
            bar = barForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/foos/add')
    else:
        fooForm = FooForm(instance=Foo())
        barForm = BarForm(instance=Bar())
    return render_to_response(
        'foo_app/foo_add.html', 
        {'foo_form': fooForm, 'bar_form': barForm}
    )
```

foo_add.html:

```
{% extends "foo_app/__base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %} 

{% block content %}

    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form foo_form layout='inline' %}
        {% bootstrap_form var_form layout='inline' %}
        {% buttons %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Save Foo
            </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

EDIT: I'm not asking how to create a form with two models. I'm *pretty* sure that the form is getting created correctly and information is getting passed as expected. I'm asking why I get the 403 error after I have filled out the form and submitted it.

Here is what the generated HTML looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id_foo-a">A</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_foo-a" name="foo-a" 
           placeholder="A" required="required" title="" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="id_bar-b">B</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_bar-b" min="0" name="bar-b" 
           placeholder="B" required="required" title="" type="number" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Save Foo
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 2 models 1 form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512972/django-2-models-1-form)

Comment: Sorry @PedroLobito I phrased the question incorrectly. It was an issue with ShareFile's API, not how to post with curl. I was making a simple mistake with my call to the API, but figured it out. I should have let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`. This ensures that the template is rendered with the `request`, which allows the `csrf_token` tag to work.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo_add(request):
    ...
    return render(
        request,
        'foo_app/foo_add.html', 
        {'foo_form': fooForm, 'bar_form': barForm},
    )
```