# how to render and save 2 models in 1 template in Django

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have 2 models with a  ForeignKey
relationship .

Model1

………

Model2

fc = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
…...

no proxy and abstract model...
 needed???

Is it any chance to render it in 1 template? ( it’s done already) and save both forms in the correspondent  models simultaneously? I have written some code(bellow).. it works, but in secondary model fc_id( a key that is in charge for connection to a model1 correspondent object would be set   to null, that is ,model2’s data saves, but irrelevant to model1. Model1 saves OK.

Sorry for the banal question, if so

THX

tried [Django 2 models 1 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512972/django-2-models-1-form)

```py
def viewname(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = FORM1(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="form1")
        form2 = FORM2(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="form2")
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()  # has to do smt with COMMIT=FALSE do smt and COMMIT=TRUE  then ???
            form2.save()
            return redirect(reverse_lazy("someURL"))
    else:
        form1 = FORM1(prefix="form1")
        form2 = FORM2(prefix="form2")
        context = {"form1": form1, "form2": form2}
        return render(request, "some.html", context)
```

model2 and model1 data should be  saved according Foreign Key relationship, but not separatelly

Comment: You could use `formsets` to do what you want

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for a good summary of a `ModelForm`'s `save()` method.

Comment: Thx a lot for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
model1 = form1.save()
model2 = form2.save(commit=False)
model2.fc = model1
model2.save()
```

Comment: well, why we should use  modelX name in  here? model1 = form1.save()
model2 = form2.save(commit=False)

 it might be easily a = form1.save(), b = form2.save(commit=False), etc, etc, for example...

Comment: What? You can use whatever name you like. They're just variables.

Comment: OK, thats makes sense